# attach a file from directory and send to email with codeigniter

Tags: php, file-upload, codeigniter-2, uploadify, email-attachments

I am a newbie with codeigniter and I want to build a website using codeigniter framework. From first, it look fine I can use database, validation, email, session and then I try to attach a file and send with email :

> $this->email->attach('/path/ofyour/constan/file.anything');

thats work too.

since that is a website I want my client to choose file they want to upload.
I try many method, and many of them tell to upload a file to server root and get the file_data, use file_data[file_patch]

> $this->email->attach('file_data[file_path]');

the problem is:

1. since code igniter cant upload multiple data I must use plugin. I tried and its PAIN
2. I thing its not effective, upload data to server root and then to email?
3. it better to just get file_path of upload file and send them to email, how?

I build it with jquery mobile, what must I do?

## Update

ok i decide to use uploadify i search every website and then i found [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/109751/) and my code is

uploadify.php

```
<?php
/*
*   Functions taken from CI_Upload Class
*
*/
    
    function set_filename($path, $filename, $file_ext, $encrypt_name = FALSE)
    {
        if ($encrypt_name == TRUE)
        {       
            mt_srand();
            $filename = md5(uniqid(mt_rand())).$file_ext;   
        }
    
        if ( ! file_exists($path.$filename))
        {
            return $filename;
        }
    
        $filename = str_replace($file_ext, '', $filename);
        
        $new_filename = '';
        for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++)
        {           
            if ( ! file_exists($path.$filename.$i.$file_ext))
            {
                $new_filename = $filename.$i.$file_ext;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($new_filename == '')
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return $new_filename;
        }
    }
    
    function prep_filename($filename) {
       if (strpos($filename, '.') === FALSE) {
          return $filename;
       }
       $parts = explode('.', $filename);
       $ext = array_pop($parts);
       $filename    = array_shift($parts);
       foreach ($parts as $part) {
          $filename .= '.'.$part;
       }
       $filename .= '.'.$ext;
       return $filename;
    }
    
    function get_extension($filename) {
       $x = explode('.', $filename);
       return '.'.end($x);
    } 


// Uploadify v1.6.2
// Copyright (C) 2009 by Ronnie Garcia
// Co-developed by Travis Nickels
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
   //$client_id = $_GET['client_id'];
   $file_temp = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
   $file_name = prep_filename($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
   $file_ext = get_extension($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
   $real_name = $file_name;
   $newf_name = set_filename($path, $file_name, $file_ext);
   $file_size = round($_FILES['Filedata']['size']/1024, 2);
   $file_type = preg_replace("/^(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $_FILES['Filedata']['type']);
   $file_type = strtolower($file_type);
   $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$path) . $newf_name;
   move_uploaded_file($file_temp,$targetFile);

   $filearray = array();
   $filearray['file_name'] = $newf_name;
   $filearray['real_name'] = $real_name;
   $filearray['file_ext'] = $file_ext;
   $filearray['file_size'] = $file_size;
   $filearray['file_path'] = $targetFile;
   $filearray['file_temp'] = $file_temp;
   //$filearray['client_id'] = $client_id;

   $json_array = json_encode($filearray);
   echo $json_array;
}else{
    echo "1";   
}
```

i dont relly know what is going on here, like i said i am a newbie but i know something that $json_array, that array hold my data $filearray, that is data file uploaded. mission one complete

now my controller: upload.php

```
<?php
class Upload extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->helper('url');

    }
    /*
    *   Display upload form
    */
    function index()
    {
        
        $this->load->view('view');
    }
    
    
    /*
    *   Handles JSON returned from /js/uploadify/upload.php
    */
    function uploadify()
    {
        
        //Decode JSON returned by /js/uploadify/upload.php
        $file = $this->input->post('filearray');
        $data['json'] = json_decode($file);
        
        $this->load->view('uploadify',$data);
    }
    
}
/* End of File /application/controllers/upload.php */
```

my plan is send the data in onComplete function

my view :view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Uploadify and Codeigniter Tutorial</title>
<?php
   $this->load->helper('html');
   echo link_tag('http://uploadify_tutorial/uploadify/uploadify.css');
   echo '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
   echo '<script src="http://localhost/uploadify_tutorial/uploadify/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
   echo '<script src="http://localhost/uploadify_tutorial/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
$uploadpath="";
$uploadpath=str_ireplace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],"", realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
$uploadpath=str_ireplace("index.php","",$uploadpath);
?>


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                                        
                    $("#upload").uploadify({
                            uploader: '<?php echo base_url();?>uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                            script: '<?php echo base_url();?>uploadify/uploadify.php',
                            cancelImg: '<?php echo base_url();?>uploadify/cancel.png',
                            folder: '/uploads',
                            scriptAccess: 'always',
                            multi: true,
                            'onError' : function (a, b, c, d) {
                                 if (d.status == 404)
                                    alert('Could not find upload script.');
                                 else if (d.type === "HTTP")
                                    alert('error '+d.type+": "+d.status);
                                 else if (d.type ==="File Size")
                                    alert(c.name+' '+d.type+' Limit: '+Math.round(d.sizeLimit/1024)+'KB');
                                 else
                                    alert('error '+d.type+": "+d.text);
                                },
                            'onComplete'   : function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                                                //Post response back to controller
                                                $.post('<?php echo site_url('upload/uploadify');?>',{filearray: response},function(info){
                                                    $("#target").append(info);  //Add response returned by controller                                                                         
                                                });                                         
                            }
                    });             
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Uploadify Example</h1>
    
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/index');?>
    
    <p>
        <label for="Filedata">Choose a File</label><br/>
        <?php echo form_upload(array('name' => 'Filedata', 'id' => 'upload'));?>
        <a href="javascript:$('#upload').uploadifyUpload();">Upload File(s)</a>
    </p>
    
    
    <?php echo form_close();?>
    
    <div id="target">
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my view : uploadify

```
<html>
    <ul>
    
        <li>Extension: <?php echo $json->{'file_ext'};?></li>
        <li>File Size: <?php echo $json->{'file_size'};?></li>
        <li>File Path: <?php echo $json->{'file_path'};?></li>
    </ul>
    </html>
```

and then parsing that json_array variable to my view, that is the plans, but in reality that code doesn work the data is undefined
an error Trying to get property of non-object i use this code [here](https://bitbucket.org/pickupman/codeigniter-uploadify), I suppose the problem is with json

i just want to use the data file uploaded if anyone can solve that problem please share it or send me CI+uploadify program to my email, if anyone expert about CI and Uploadify plugin please make the tutorial step by step how to use it, step by step, i think it would be great help for newbie like me

thanks....

my email :saya.dean@gmail.com

Comment: what plugin(s) have you tried?  I've implemented uploadify and it wasn't too difficult to do.

Comment: really, can you give me tutorial about it or send me CI+uploadifity thats work for you in my email, cos i try that to, search the method, download all uploadifity+CI, no one works fine

Comment: can uploadifity solve all my problem? which variable that hold every file upload patch? how can i use that variable to put in attacement? it will be great, great, great help if you can solve it

Comment: please see my revised answer.  I can't code the answer for you but do some research and give it a shot yourself.  If your stuck post more code and ask for help.

Comment: in your view.php you have the onComplete defined with "fileObj", not "file".  if it is "fileObj" then your filename alert should look like:   alert('The file name is '+fileObj.name+);

Comment: thanks jco yup its working, now i try to use json to work with my CI, but its not working.... they say Trying to get property of non-object do you know why? anyway which method do you do to pass the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really clear on where you are running into a problem.  'that variable' will be the files you uploaded, yes?  Create an array of the filepaths as they get uploaded and when the upload is done cycle through each for email attachment.
Have you checked other answers on the site?  Maybe take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079325/php-send-multiple-attachments-with-email).  But [CI's documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html) clearly states that you can use:

```
$this->email->attach('/path/to/that_file.jpg');
```

multiple times.

### **Update:**

You can either try using the onUploadSuccess function in uploadify to append each file name to something that you can use later...

```
  'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
     alert('The file name is ' + file.name);
     ...
```

OR from within uploadify.php. From there you can store what you need for attaching after.

**In your case I'd stick with modifying the uploadify.php**.  You'll have to give it a shot and post some code if you are stuck, but there are plenty of places to get some ideas like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363317/uploadify-rename-uploaded-file) and [here](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/customizing-the-server-side-upload-script/)

Comment: please see my update question, that is the best code i can get